# Website isn't responsive

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, design

I noticed the Stack Overflow website isn't responsive in some parts. Mostly I don't care because the important stuff is always visible, namely:

- question/answer content
- comments
- votes
- moderating tools (flag, close, ...)

but it's completely different with *reviewing* the content and it's really annoying when I split the screen. Obviously I can make a userscript to just resize it however I like. The problem here isn't that the *whole* website isn't responsive to the browser (view/viewport?) size, but that only *some* parts aren't and those are:

- question/answer content
- links to other Stack Exchange sites

[image]

Although this type of "design" with a splitted screen (mine with 1920px half) seems to be useful for deciding whether to open or close rather than skip, it still leaves the buttons out even though there is a lot of free space for them.

Can't you make at least the button panel to be responsive like you dit with the top panel? It's really wasting the space (and time when scrolling/maximizing).

The problematic parts are:

```
div.review-bar.width  # absolute, can be removed to fetch width from parent

div#content.width     # absolute, can be corrected or reloaded dynamically
div#content.margin    # auto (centers the content)
div#footer-sites      # too much content
```

About the footer sites, I have no clue what is the sort behind this (maybe visits or count of users?), but I believe the table with links is created dynamically, so just add a limit for the width and move the undisplayable content to the `more (x)` part instead of stretching a website with it. Pls? ^-^

Comment: to downvoter: please give me a reason for the downvote except that "you can", it's rather useful to get some feedback :)

Comment: responsiveness is not a feature so it can't a be a bug and I personally doubt if dev time needs to be spend on this. That could explain the down vote as well.

Comment: Thing is that this has been brought up many times before, and that nothing is being changed. In fact, [they're making it worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296128/166789). Bringing it up *yet again* probably isn't all that useful.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I edited the tag and voted for closing (the lovely button to accept the duplicate disappeared :( ). Apparently it'll be fixed only locally for me, meh.